# Preciso mudar o nome desse campo 'Biblioteca01' para uma palavra de no máximo 10 caracteres, exemplo: 'BIBILIOT01'

Tags: sql-server

Porém por conta do WHEN S.codSala LIKE 'B%', não aceita.

[inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T90l7.jpg)

```
CASE
WHEN S.codSala LIKE 'A%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'B%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'C%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'D%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'E%'OR S.codSala LIKE 'F%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'G%'
THEN S.codSala
WHEN S.codSala = '%Biblioteca01%' THEN 'BIBLIOT1'
```

ELSE ''
END AS CODSALA,

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa usar outro CASE depois do THEN e podes validar da mesma forma que tentou, mas recomendo algo mais genérico, por exemplo:

```
CASE WHEN S.codSala LIKE 'A%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'B%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'C%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'D%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'E%'OR S.codSala LIKE 'F%' OR S.codSala LIKE 'G%' THEN 
    CASE WHEN (LEN(S.codSala) > 10) THEN 
        LEFT(S.codSala, 8) + RIGHT(S.codSala, 2) 
    ELSE 
        S.codSala 
    END
ELSE 
    '' 
END AS CODSALA
```

Comment: Valeu cara, deu certo!